# Visual Studio 2013 Web Deploy Package and Physical IIS Path at runtime

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, msdeploy, webdeploy

When I import a Web Deploy Package into `IIS 7` it installs to a physical path under the default IIS directory (`c:\inetpub\www`) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I am using **Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition** to create the `Web Deploy Package` and following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx).  At the end of that link it says you can specify the `physical IIS path` but I want the user installing it to be able to choose the `physical IIS path` at runtime not have it set the same for all installations.

Is it possible to do this with a Web Deploy Package?  I want to avoid creating an installer with Wix.

Comment: From your link, you will go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410108%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which you will see no option for Physical IIS path. Actually the same in your VS 2013 Community. IMO, when user uses WebDeployPackage in one machine, don't need to pay attention to IIS path, just need to change `IIS Web Application Name` inside `WebApi.SetParameters.xml` if wanted

Comment: I think you're right.  I was trying to make Web Deploy Package do more than it was intended for.  I wanted to give the person installing it more control to specify the physical IIS install path but I don't think it was designed to allow that.  I'll have to publish with the file system option if I want to let them do that and let them setup IIS manually.